# MLA 8 and Date Accessed - not required, but still preferable?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, mla

From the newest MLA guide:

> "Citing the date when an online work was consulted is now optional."

What is the common consensus regarding whether inclusion of the date is still **preferable**?

Context: I'm knocking out a bibliography for a PhD student.

Source: https://www.mla.org/MLA-Style/What-s-New-in-the-Eighth-Edition

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, it depends on the teacher. Some teachers may force it, others may want it, and others might not care.  If you aren't sure what the teacher want, I would include it to be safe.